# How to listen to form onsubmit event with GeckoFx

Tags: c#, geckofx

Using GeckoFx, I want to listen to the "onsubmit" event for a form on a given webpage. Is this possible, and can someone nudge me in the right direction?

I've made a small C# application that simply opens a webpage with a form using GeckoFx. I've grabbed the form as a GeckoHtmlElement, but this is where I get stuck. I see no way to listen to events on the element.
I've also tried to grab the form as a GeckoFormElement.

```cs
GeckoHtmlElement form = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("form")[0];
Listener ear = new Listener();
            ear.OnSubmit += Ear_OnSubmit;
            form.GetEventTarget().AddEventListener("onsubmit", ear, true, false, 0);
```

Where Listener is a simple class:

```
class Listener : nsIDOMEventListener
    {
        public event OnSubmit OnSubmit;

        public void HandleEvent(nsIDOMEvent @event)
        {
            OnSubmit?.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately I am not even sure I'm going in the right direction, so the code provided may be entirely off track.